# Proofs of elementary identities on 2 sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Apologies for not having the proper math notation symbols here, but I am trying to disprove that ((A or B) and B complement) is in the subset of A. This is what I have so far:

1.) (B complement and (A or B)) = (B complement and A) or (B complement and B) - Distributive.

2.) (B complement and B) = empty set - Domination on 1.

3.) (B complement and A) or (empty set) = (B complement and A) - Identity on 1 and 2.

From here, I know that (B complement and A) is equal to the ((Universe - B) and A), which is not in the subset of A, but I am not sure how to formally show this.

Comment: (1)  "and" and "or" should be used to connect statements, not sets.  I assume you mean "union" where you have written "or" and "intersection" where you have "and".  (2)  The easiest way to prove that one set is a subset of another is to start by assuming that some arbitrary object $x$ is an element of the first set and then proving that $x$ is an element of the second set.  (3)  Did you really mean "disprove" rather than "prove"?

Comment: Does "is in the subset of $A$" mean "is a subset of $A$"?  If not, what does it mean?

Comment: $(A \cup B) \cap B^\complement = (A \cap B^\complement) \cup (B \cap B^\complement) = (A \cap B^\complement) \cup \emptyset = A \cap B^\complement \subseteq A$ by simple set arithmetic.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Venn diagrams?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma wouldn't ∩∁ not be a subset of A? ∩∁ means that some arbitrary x is in A and everything that is not B (Universe - B). How is this a subset of A?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Unless we can say that A is the set that contains everything (U), then can we say that the U is a subset of U?

Comment: If $x \in A \cap B^\complement$ then in particular $x \in A$ so the subset relation is trivial.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Is there a law of set theory that this applies too?